# Extend Mage_Sales_Model_Order

Tags: php, magento, model, magento-1.9, extend

how do i start ? hrmmmm. 
ok , right now Im trying to extend the mage_sales_mode_order . but this error appear.
**Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php on line 74**

i don't know what is the problem because i already try using the same code extend different magento site but is working. 
but below is what that i do and thanks in advance.

**MageCustom/Sales/Model/Order.php**

```
class MageCustom_Sales_Model_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order
{

public function queueNewOrderEmail($forceMode = false)
{
    $storeId = $this->getStore()->getId();


    if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewOrderEmail($storeId)) {
        return $this;
    }

    // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
    $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
    $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);

    // Start store emulation process
    /** @var $appEmulation Mage_Core_Model_App_Emulation */
    $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
    $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

    try {
        // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
        $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
            ->setIsSecureMode(true);
        $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
        $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
        throw $exception;
    }

    // Stop store emulation process
    $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

    // Retrieve corresponding email template id and customer name
    if ($this->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_GUEST_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getBillingAddress()->getName();
    } else {
        $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
        $customerName = $this->getCustomerName();
    }

    /** @var $mailer Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer */
    $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
    /** @var $emailInfo Mage_Core_Model_Email_Info */
    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($this->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
        // Add bcc to customer email
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

    // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy'
    if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'copy') {
        foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($email);
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }
    }

    // Set all required params and send emails
    $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
    $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
    $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    ));

    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
    $emailQueue = Mage::getModel('core/email_queue');
    $emailQueue->setEntityId($this->getId())
        ->setEntityType(self::ENTITY)
        ->setEventType(self::EMAIL_EVENT_NAME_NEW_ORDER)
        ->setIsForceCheck(!$forceMode);

    //$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
    $mailer->send();
    Mage::log('new order trigger email', null, 'email.log');

    $this->setEmailSent(true);
    $this->_getResource()->saveAttribute($this, 'email_sent');

    return $this;
}
```

**MageCustom/Sales/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageCustom_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MageCustom_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <MageCustom_Sales>
                <class>MageCustom_Sales_Model</class>
            </MageCustom_Sales>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>MageCustom_Sales_Model_Order</order>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>   
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**MageCustom_Sales.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageCustom_Sales>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MageCustom_Sales>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Your class and configuration are all correct assuming they exist in `app/code/local`, except for the `active` setting in `MageCustom_Sales.xml`:

```
<active>false</active>
```

Turn it on, clear your cache and try again :)

---

### Testing

#### > With Magerun

If you've got [magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun), you can use it to test your rewrite:

```
n98-magerun.phar dev:class:lookup model sales/order
# Model sales/order resolves to MageCustom_Sales_Model_Order
```

If you don't see the above resolution, you may have conflicts with the rewrite, but it's more likely that your rewrite configuration is wrong.

If you don't have Magerun - get it! You won't regret it.

#### > Without Magerun

You can drop a custom script into the root directory of your Magento project just to test the class alias:

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
var_dump(get_class(Mage::getModel('sales/order')));
```

Run it from command line via `php myTestFile.php`, or from browser via `http://magento.local/myTestFile.php`.

If it works, you should see `string(28) "MageCustom_Sales_Model_Order"`. If it doesn't you'll see `bool(false)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Please share your full file paths

Comment: i edit the comment. sorry . i keep click the enter button. hahah
i already try what you state above and clear cache.
i run the test.php and it shows `string(28) "MageCustom_Sales_Model_Order" `.

but the thing is , error appear when i try to open an order on admin view.
Sales->Order-> (Then View One of the Order).
then the error appear.

Comment: Then there should be no problem :) Try restarting your web server. The line in the order controller that throws the error is saying it can't resolve the sales model. Ensure you've cleared cache, restart web server, try again.

Comment: i'll try clear cache. then turn the module.
I go to Sales->Order on admin view and this error appear.
`Fatal error: Class 'MageCustom_Sales_Model_Order' not found in /home/optima/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 31396`
Have you encounter this before ?

Comment: Turn off your compiler

Comment: thanks @Robbie Averill.
its working. no wonder my module is not read.
thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112455/discussion-between-mohd-nizam-and-robbie-averill).

Answer (score 0):

Make it sure that you have your custom module inside the local folder and enable your module by inserting true inside the active tag.

```
<active>true</active>
```